# Automatically get the value of textbox after selecting value of combobox in vb6

Tags: mysql, database, vb6, combobox

I have a table `products` with 6 columns including column **PRICE**. What i want to achive is this:

- When I selected a value from combo box, the next text box which is **Price** will automatically be filled up from database table `products`.

Ex: Table Products

```
ProductName     Price
Mango           12
Apple           15
```

Combo Box Values:

```
Mango
Apple
```

Combo box text box value:

```
Mango
```

**PRICE** text box value automatically be filled up with:

```
12
```

Tried Code:

```
Private Sub Price()
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command

If txtProdName.txt Is Not Nothing Then

With Cmd
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "SELECT price from products where productname=txtProdname.txt"
    Set Rs = .Execute
End With

txtPrice = Rs.Fields
 End If
 End Sub
```

I'm trying this one all day but this doesn't work, how to correct this one?Really confused to this.

Comment: Try txtPrice = Rs.Fields(0).Value

Comment: it has error, please help me

Comment: Your query string is wrong too - try something like `.CommandText = "SELECT price from products where productname='" & txtProdname.txt & "'"`

Comment: The error is in "If txtProdName.txt Is Not Nothing Then" Part..any suggestion?It says "Iinvalid Use of Object"

Comment: My VB6 is rusty but something like `if Len(txtProdName.txt) > 0` might be a usable test.

Comment: in combobox, should i use the change() to call the function price?

Comment: Like I said, my VB6 is rusty but generally if you're not sure which event to trap, trap everything you think is likely and show some messages in each handler. Then you can see where you need to put your code by running your app and selecting from the combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: This serrve as sample...Hope it helps

```
Private sub CboiPAQ_click()
Set rsiPAQs = New ADODB.Recordset 
With rsiPAQs 
.ActiveConnection = cnMHS 
.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
.CursorType = adOpenStatic 
.LockType = adLockPessimistic 
.Source = "SELECT location FROM iPAQs WHERE iPAQ=" & "'" & CboiPAQ.text & "'" 
.Open 
txtbox.text=rsiPAQs("location")
End With 
End sub
```